# WPF Navigating From one page to another inside a window

Tags: wpf, navigation, uri

I am trying to write a WPF application. The general outline of the application is as follows: There is a main window(Note that the main window is a full screen application) and there are several pages(Possibly 25) and I want to navigate from one page to another with a button click event on each page. What will be the best way to achieve this?
I have tried creating a Frame on the MainWindow and then use the frame to display pages, but my problem is that I can not navigate from one page to another from a button click on the pages. I am new to this and I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score -1):

You could of at least tried a Google mate, this information is abundant, but because you thought typing a paragraph here was easier, I shall save you the trouble.... http://paulstovell.com/blog/wpf-navigation

Comment: It is a good thing you asked me. Truly speaking I have googled this a 100 times already. All the post out there suggest to start out the application from a "page" rather than a "window". I ran into complications because the "page" would not go full screen unless I explicitly give a dimension. I preferred starting from a window and then navigate to a page(Which works). But the problem is since I am displaying the page on a frame inside the main window, I cannot refresh the frame with a new "page" from a button click on the previous page. I hope this clears things more.

Comment: @nishan_vodoo Ahh, I figured this was just another "Please provide me with code" question, my apologies for being a little harsh. If your code matches what is in the link, and there is still a problem, you probably should post your code (the relevant bits), it will help people provide you with an answer. The only help I can provide atm, based on what you have provided and my understanding of it, is that you need a reference to your main window instance from your page, then do the navigation based on this (MainWindow mainWin = Application.Current.MainWindow; then mainWin.myframe.Navigate();)